# Sails.js + apidocjs + grunt - auto generate documentation

Tags: node.js, sails.js, api-doc

I'm new to Sails.js and Node.js and I have problems with creating documentation for my application.

Here's my steps:

- installed apidoc by:
  `npm install apidoc -g`
- installed grunt module:
  `npm install grunt-apidoc --save-dev`
- added `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-apidoc');` to `Gruntfile.js`  at the bottom
- created `grunt.initConfig` file and put:

`apidoc: {
      myapp: {
        src: "api/controllers/",
        dest: "apidoc/"
      }
    }`

Then I'm trying to run multiple things, and none of them produces my api documentation:

- sails lift
- grunt
- grunt default
- node app.js

If I run it manually by `apidoc -i api/controllers/ -o apidoc/` it's working properly.

What am I doing wrong? How to  do it?

Comment: Have you registered the task. Something like `grunt.registerTask('apidoc', ['apidoc']);`

Answer (score 2):

Super late answer!

From my experience modifying the asset pipeline you'd be better off:

1. Install apidoc and the Grunt module as in the Question
2. Create a new file in `tasks/config/apidoc.js:

   ```
   module.exports = function (grunt) {
       grunt.config.set('apidoc', {
       myapp: {
         src: "api/controllers/",
         dest: "apidoc/"
       }
     });
     grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-apidoc');
   };
   ```
3. Edit `tasks/register/compileAssets.js` (or wherever you want the task to be run):

   ```
   module.exports = function (grunt) {
     grunt.registerTask('compileAssets', [
       'clean:dev',
       'jst:dev',
       'less:dev',
       'copy:dev',
       'coffee:dev',
       'apidoc:myapp' // <-- This will now run every time your assets are compiled
     ]);
   };
   ```

Hope this helps someone